# Como deixar em um boxplot no R, todos os valores do eixo x escritos no gráfico?

Tags: r

Estou plotando um gráfico do tipo boxplot no R, porém alguns valores ele está omitindo. Fica apenas o risquinho no eixo x referente ao boxplot, porém não aparece o nome daquele boxplot.
Eu acredito que seja devido a quantidade de boxplots que existe dentro do gráfico. 
Alguém sabe como resolver ?
Estou plotando assim:

```
boxplot(dados$Peso ~ dados$Idade,
        xlab='Times (hours)', ylab='Weight (grams)',
        outline=F)
```

Comment: Olá, apenas essas informações dificulta-nos te ajudar, é necessário fornecer uma amostra do seu conjunto de dados para entendermos o problema. Edite sua pegunta, fornecendo essa amostra, use `dput(dados)` para capitá-la.

Comment: Obrigado Fernandes, mas eu acabei de conseguir resolver. Fui tentando várias combinações aqui e deu certo. O meu output estava com as dimensões pequenas e isso de alguma forma estava atrapalhando alguns valores do eixo x. Tudo o que eu fiz foi aumentar as dimensões laterais do gráfico e deu certo.

Comment: Seria interessante então responder a pergunta com a tua solução, para que outras pessoas, no futuro, cheguem aqui e vejam como aumentar as as dimensões laterais do gráfico.

Comment: Opa, erro meu. Como uso o RStudio, bem acima de onde fica o gráfico, existe uma opção com o nome "Export", depois "Save as pdf" e daí ele te deixa você colocar as dimensões do arquivo. Foi nesse ponto que eu fui testando combinações. Depois é só salvar.

Comment: Assim como @MarcusNunes sugeriu, responda a sua questão no campo abaixo, e não nos comentários. Assim, essa questão não é mais marcada como "não respondida". Além, por que fazer um boxplot entre duas variáveis numéricas? Não seria melhor fazer um gráfico de dispersão?

Answer (score 1):

Possivelmente esse problema de não conseguir visualizar os [boxplots](https://gpestatistica.netlify.com/blog/boxplot) é devido ao tipo das variáveis. Como ambas são numéricas (a partir da descrição do seu texto), não deveria utilizar tal gráfico. Tal gráfico deve ser utilizada quando têm-se uma variável numérica e 1 ou 2 categóricas.

## Criando o exemplo de Boxplot de Idade e Peso:

```
set.seed(123234)
dados <- data.frame(Peso = rnorm(150, 80, 20),
           Idade = round(rnorm(150, 70, 25)))
boxplot(dados$Peso ~ dados$Idade,
        xlab='Idade', ylab='Weight (grams)',
        outline=F)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como a `Idade` é uma variável numérica, para cada uma das Idades a função `boxplot` irá criar um boxplot para o `Peso`. Por isso que na maioria dos casos aparece apenas um risco (quando não, significa que pelo menos 2 pessoas tem a mesma idade), que nesse caso, representa a mediana. Tal representação é completamente errada. O correto é um gráfico de [dispersão](https://gpestatistica.netlify.com/blog/correlacao/):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]